# Want help in understanding verilog constructs

Tags: verilog, variable-assignment

I am new to understanding Verilog as this language requires thinking in terms of synthesis.

While doing some program I found that:

```
begin
buf_inm[row][col] =temp_data;
      #1 mux_data=buf_inm[row][col];
end
```

gave correct results than

```
begin
buf_inm[row][col] =temp_data;
       mux_data=buf_inm[row][col];
end
```

in terms of assignments of variables.

Can anybody explain what is the difference between these two?

In any other higher level languages construct 2 (without delay) would have given correct assignments.

Thanking you,

Yours sincerely,
R. Ganesan.

Comment: @R Ganesan : Give more information regarding your expectation and your tb.

Comment: Need more information, regarding surrounding code and testbench

Answer (score 0):

First of all #1 is a one time scale delay that you can use in simulation, but it is not synthesizeable.  When you say "gave correct results", it might help if you explained what results you are seeing, but my guess is that you assigned something to the 2 dimensional vector, and then you assign that to the max_data and are expecting mux_data to be what temp data was.  Is it retaining old data?  Is it undefined?

That said, I would say the difference is a synthesizeable assignment versus a non-sythesizeble one.  In the first case you should see two state changes separated by a timescale unit.  The second case, because it is blocking, should see both values update in zero-time, and in the order as written top to bottom.  If you aren't seeing that, something else is potentially at foot here.  What tool are you using?  Tool version?  Maybe you can share your full code and test bench so we can see why your results are unexpected.